# compiling less file using angular2 cli

Tags: angular, less, angular-cli

I've following settings inside angular-cli-build

```
Angular2App(defaults,{
 lessCompiler: {
     includePaths: [
       'src/app'
      ],
   }
})
```

I'have two test less files in `src` directory.

test1.less

```
//some code
```

test2.less

```
@import "test1.less";
```

when I `ng build` the project it throws an error

```
Build failed.
File: input (1)
The Broccoli Plugin: [LESSPlugin] failed with:
undefined
```

I've tried [issue 873](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/873) temporary solution. The error gone.but could not find any compiled css files.
please help. how you compile customized bootstrap less files in angular2 project which is built by angular-cli.

how could I extend the bootstrap's less file's(stayed inside node_modules) with my custom lesses

Answer (score 14):

open angular-cli.json and insert a new entry into the styles array

```
"styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "less/app.less"
  ],
```

Install less if needed. I don't know if this is required. But I had done this beforehand.

```
npm install less --save
```

Comment: Works on 1.0.0-beta.25.5. Explicit less installation not needed.

Comment: I did need to install less

Answer (score 4):

If you install less with  `npm install less --save` and rename the CSS file in your component's directory, it should work. 
Works the same for sass, as described in `angular-cli` documentation/Readme file.

I made the import work by placing the `other.less` file in `/shared directory` and importing it with the full path `./src/app/shared/other.less`

`@import (less) "./src/app/shared/other.less";`

it works without an error now.

**Edit**: it seams to work with `@import (less) "./src/app/other.less";`as well.

Comment: I did what described in their doc. but its not working. only css file generating with nothing inside it. (empty). did you tried it successfully? please let me know. @JS_astronauts

Comment: I started a new project with `ng new lesstest` and it works for me, first I was trying node-sass and later I tested it with less. it works, I did not have to go in to ` angular-cli-build` and the `.css` file is compiled in `dist/app/`

Comment: would you please try if @import working or not in your setup?

Comment: but this arises another problem.. how could I extend the bootstrap's less file's(stayed inside node_modules) with my custom lesses if the @import doesn't take the relative path??? I mean bootstraps less file has written in relative paths.

Answer (score 1):

**When creating a new project :**

```
ng new project_name --style less
```

Then when you take a look at your project, you'll find a less file in every component folder rather than css one in the one hand. And in the other hand, when you look at the component.ts file of a component, you 'll find in @Component, styleUrls: ['./xxx.component**.less**'] rather than ['./xxx.component**.css**']

**For post install do like @Kaspars said:**

```
npm install less --save
```

When done :

- rename all CSS files in your component's directory to less
- change ['./xxx.component.css'] by ['./xxx.component.less'] in every component file

If you want scss rather than less, do the some thing